# .NET Core on Ubuntu - what is the proper value for the CORECLR_DIR env variable?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04, coreclr

On my Ubuntu 14 host, I'm trying to use a Node module named node-msmq, which provides a bridge to MS MSMQ
This module depends on having .NET environment installed.
I have compiles .NET on Ubuntu using git repo, and have it under /home/ubuntu/coreclr:

```
ubuntu@lin-dev-42:~/coreclr$ pwd
/home/ubuntu/coreclr

ubuntu@lin-dev-42:~/coreclr$ ls
all.locproj            clrdefinitions.cmake   crossgen.cmake                     generateversionscript.awk   README.md
bin                    clr.desktop.props      dac.cmake                          global.json                 run.cmd
build.cmd              clr.native.targets     dac.props                          init-tools.cmd              run-cppcheck.sh
build-packages.cmd     clr.props              definitionsconsistencycheck.cmake  init-tools.sh               run.sh
build-packages.sh      clr.targets            dir.props                          LICENSE.TXT                 sanitizerblacklist.txt
build.proj             cmake.definitions      dirs.proj                          netci.groovy                src
build.sh               CMakeLists.txt         dir.targets                        oacr.cfg                    sync.cmd
build-test.cmd         CODE_OWNERS.TXT        dir.traversal.targets              packages                    sync.sh
BuildToolsVersion.txt  compileoptions.cmake   Documentation                      partition.settings.targets  tests
clean.cmd              config.json            DotnetCLIVersion.txt               PATENTS.TXT                 THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES
clean.sh               CONTRIBUTING.md        enablesanitizers.sh                perf.groovy                 Tools
clr.coreclr.props      cross                  functions.cmake                    publish-packages.cmd        UpdateDependencies.ps1
clr.defines.targets    crosscomponents.cmake  generateexportedsymbols.awk        publish-packages.sh         UpdatePublishedVersions.ps1
```

my Node script looks super simple:

```
const msmq = require('node-msmq');

//var queue = msmq.openOrCreateQueue('.\\Private$\\MyAwesomeQueue');

// Send message to queue 
//queue.send('Hello from Node.JS!');
```

When I run this code, I get an error, complaining of not having env var CORECLR_DIR set correctly:

```
ubuntu@lin-dev-42:~/dev/node/msmq-producer$ node producer.js 

module.js:355
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                               ^
Error: Unable to load the CLR from the directory (��S) specified in the CORECLR_DIR environment variable.
    at Error (native)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/dev/node/msmq-producer/node_modules/node-msmq/node_modules/edge/lib/edge.js:53:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

Currently, I have this var set to:

```
ubuntu@lin-dev-42:~/dev/node/msmq-producer$ echo $CORECLR_DIR
/home/ubuntu/coreclr
```

, which, apparently, is the not right value.

What value should I set it to, in order to detect my coercer .NET environment on Ubuntu?

Comment: The path is to CoreCLR.dll which is most likely in /home/ubuntu/coreclr/bin

Comment: Why are you compiling CoreCLR, instead of using a package?

Answer (score 0):

That error is not coming from CoreCLR itself.

Based on your stack it looks like you're using `edge.js`. I just looked at the [GitHub README for edge](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge), and it says the following about that environment variable (I recommend reading the whole README):

> Edge will try to find the .NET Core runtime in the following
>   locations:
>
> - The path in the `CORECLR_DIR` environment variable, if provided
> - The current directory
> - The directory containing `edge_*.node`
> - Directories in the `PATH` environment variable. Once a directory containing the `dotnet` executable is located, we then do the
>     following to decide which version of the framework (you can have
>     several installed at once) to load
>
>   - If the `CORECLR_VERSION`
>       environment variable was specified, we try to load that version
>   - Else, if the project.json/*.deps.json has a reference to
>       `Microsoft.NETCore.App`, indicating that it was built for a specific
>       framework version, we try to load that version
>   - Otherwise, we pick
>       the maximum installed version

So the simplest answer to your question is to set that variable to the directory containing libcoreclr.so, or just run from that directory (make it the current directory).